# how to install Figaro programming language in Google Colab?

Tags: scala

How to run a project that implemented with Figaro probabilistic programming language in Google Colab? For Figaro programming, you need to install Scala, and according to the information on the (https://medium.com/@shadaj/machine-learning-with-scala-in-google-colaboratory-e6f1661f1c88) page, you can install Scala in Google Colab that according to this tutorial, Scala will be installed in Google Colab using Almond, which is a Scala kernel for Jupyter. But after installing Scala, how can install Figaro in Google Colab and run Figaro code in it?

Answer (score 2):

Figaro is just a scala library, and Almond wraps the Ammonite REPL. So to use the figaro library, you have to import it into the REPL by running the following command in your notebook:

```scala
import $ivy.`com.cra.figaro::figaro:5.0.0.0`
```